# How do I add dimensions to my numpy array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy array (50,32). I am trying to add a third and forth dimension to make it (50,32,16,16). I can't seem to figure out the best way to do this. Any help would be great.

I've tried np.expand_dims and np.newaxis, but can't seem to figure out how they work.

Comment: Do you want a (50,32,1,1) shape array, or one that repeats all values 16*16 times?

Comment: I was looking for one that would repeat all values 16 times. (50,32,16,16)

Comment: Have you looked at `np.repeat` or `np.tile`?  But depending on the use the (n,m,1,1) shape may be enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import numpy as np


original_array = np.random.rand(50, 32)


new_shape = (50, 32, 16, 16)
new_array = np.zeros(new_shape)


new_array[:, :, :original_array.shape[0], :original_array.shape[1]] = original_array.reshape(original_array.shape[0], original_array.shape[1], 1, 1)
```